# Problem executing data inclusion scripts in SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql, sql-server

Microsoft SQL Server 2014 - 12.0.2269.0 (X64) Jun 10 2015 03:35:45
Express Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1  (Build 7601: Service Pack 1)

Language: Português (Brasil)

When generating a script for adding data to SQL Server 2014, if the tables have columns of type `datetime`, which cause an error trying to run this script later against the same database.

[image]

[image]

Script generated by "Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio" itself:

```
USE [BancoTeste]
GO

DELETE FROM [dbo].[Vendas]
GO

SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Vendas] ON 
GO

INSERT [dbo].[Vendas] ([Codigo], [Data]) 
VALUES (8, CAST(N'2019-10-29 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Vendas] ([Codigo], [Data]) 
VALUES (11, CAST(N'2019-10-29 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Vendas] ([Codigo], [Data]) 
VALUES (12, CAST(N'2019-10-29 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Vendas] ([Codigo], [Data]) 
VALUES (13, CAST(N'2019-10-29 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Vendas] ([Codigo], [Data]) 
VALUES (14, CAST(N'2019-10-29 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Vendas] ([Codigo], [Data]) 
VALUES (15, CAST(N'2019-10-29 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime))
GO

SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Vendas] OFF
GO
```

When attempting to run this script, SQL Server throws the following error message:

> Converting an nvarchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

[image]

If I change the generated script to a date in the format specific to my region:

```
INSERT [dbo].[Vendas] ([Data]) VALUES (CAST('29/10/2019' AS DateTime))
```

It works normally. Leading me to believe that this is a region or language problem.

Very strange (not to say comical)! SQL cannot handle a script of its own.

Any tips will be most welcome.

Comment: Add SET DATEFORMAT at the top of the script: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-dateformat-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: ErikEJ, the expression "SET DATEFORMAT ymd;" solved my problem. Thanks. Would you like to write a reply, with the instruction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add

```
SET DATEFORMAT ymd
```

at the start of the script

Comment: Many thanks for the reply!
It would be great if SQL Server itself included this blessed statement, automatically in the script.

Comment: It would be better if the script was generated using ODBC literals! https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/reference/develop-app/date-time-and-timestamp-literals?view=sql-server-ver15